# Correct spacing in alignat enviornment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignat

I am trying to write down few equations with `alignat` with following code

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
...
\begin{alignat}{4}
G &=    &&I_1       &&\wedge        &&I_2 \\
G &=\neg&&I_1       &&\wedge        &&I_2 \\
G &=\neg&&I_1       &&\wedge    \neg&&I_2 \\
G &=    &&I_1       &&\wedge    \neg&&I_2 \\
G &=    &&I_1       &&\vee          &&I_2 
\end{alignat}
```

I am getting following output

[image]

As you can see it is not properly aligned. I want all 'I's and symbols to be aligned vertically. What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By providing `\wedge` and `\vee` with subsequent empty atoms rather than the tab boundary, you let `amsmath` know to format it as a binary operator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{4}
G &=    &&I_1       &&\wedge      {}&&I_2 \\
G &=\neg&&I_1       &&\wedge      {}&&I_2 \\
G &=\neg&&I_1       &&\wedge    \neg&&I_2 \\
G &=    &&I_1       &&\wedge    \neg&&I_2 \\
G &=    &&I_1       &&\vee        {}&&I_2 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Holy Sh*t. I would have never guessed this :O

Comment: @Dexter Compare `$a+b$` to `$a{+}b$`.  In the latter case, the `+` does not give proper spacing because the braces prevent the `+` from "seeing" the surrounding atoms.  It thus sets itself as a simple glyph, rather than as a math operator.  In the same way, `&` prevents operators from seeing beyond the boundary (though `amsmath` has a way of coping with information across the left-hand boundary).